# react native call setState within componentDidUpdate error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I've a multiscreen app using react-navigation and passing a prop from CameraScreen to HomeScreen called 'barcode' like so:

```
takePicture() {
        //Redirect 
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {barcode: true});
    }
```

Source: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html

On home screen I'm listening for the prop update within componentDidMount and if barcode is true, setState to render a new component like so:

```
 componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.props.navigation.getParam('barcode') === true) {
      this.setState({
        barcodeActive: true
      })
    }
  }
```

I get the error `Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded` - from calling setState within componentDidMount. I understand it's in an infinite loop with no break.

How can I listen for when this prop is passed to setState or is there a better way to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: The full signature is `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)` so you can simply do `if (!prevState.barCode) ...` to exit the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `prevProps` argument, and then compare current and previous values of `barcode`. If they are not the same, then you can update your state.

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    if(this.props.navigation.getParam('barcode') !== prevProps.navigation.getParam('barcode')) {

      if( this.props.navigation.getParam('barcode')) {
        this.setState({
          barcodeActive: true
        })
       }

    }
  }
```

Comment: I see! An extra condition to ensure the loop breaks, thanks a lot this works perfectly. Will mark correct when stack allows me to.